# pure-react-carousel - I want to handle the uneven width of slides that are being mapped, the display count is disturbed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, pure-react-carousel

I'm encountering an issue with the pure-react-carousel library when dealing with slides of varying widths. The problem arises when I'm dynamically mapping the slides, and their content causes different widths. This leads to inconsistencies in the display count and sometimes results in extra space before or after the slides.

I've tried to set the `slidesToShow` prop, but the challenge is that I don't know the exact size of each slide while mapping them. Some slides might have a width of 50, while others have a width of 150, making it challenging to keep the display consistent.

Comment: You'd probably be better to add code or a demo to your question.

Comment: you can reproduce the issue by having hard coded uneven slides

Comment: Yes, but by providing demo/code you're more likely to get answers...